# Update list of records using LINQ

Tags: linq, gridview

I have a editable GridView on my webforms page. Users can enter records and after hitting submit using LINQ I am inserting the records to the database. It is working absolutely fine.

I am not able to figure out how to update the records. I am populating the records in the GridView once the user hits the submit button, I need to update the existing records.

How can this be done?

```
Dim db as new empDBDataContext
Dim rw As GridViewRow
Dim emp as new employee
emp.name="test"
emp.city="NYC"
emp.age=40
For each rw in GridView1.Rows
   Dim cert as new certifications
   cert.Name=CType(rw.FindControl("lblCert"), TextBox).Text
   cert.score=CType(rw.FindControl("lblScore"), TextBox).Text     
   emp.cert.add(cert)
Next

db.emp.insertonsubmit(emp)
db.submitChanges()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your unique identifier for certifications to select the rows from the database (I used `lblId` as the control name).  Then, set the properties to the updated values.  It's very similar to what you're doing for the insert.  Please excuse my VB syntax ignorance...

```
For each rw in GridView1.Rows
 // Load the cert based on the ID of the row.
 Dim cert
 cert = (from c in db.certifications
        where c.Id = (int) CType(rw.FindControl("lblId"), TextBox).Text).Single()
 // Update the values.
 cert.Name=CType(rw.FindControl("lblCert"), TextBox).Text
 cert.score=CType(rw.FindControl("lblScore"), TextBox).Text
Next

// Submit all the changes.
db.submitChanges()
```